# Ms Teams navigating to personal tab using deeplink

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I have encountered an issue while trying to create a deep link for my Microsoft Teams tab. My tab opens a web app built with Angular, which consists of a homepage and multiple internal pages. Specifically, I am having trouble creating a link that will open a particular route ('/article/1414') within the personal tab.

I have attempted to create the deep link using the following format:

The **personal tab will open** (home page). However, I have not been successful in getting the link to navigate to the specified route (/article/{articleId}).

When creating the link, I have set the following parameters:

`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/<entityId>?webUrl=<entityWebUrl>&label=<entityLabel>`

entityWebUrl: https://site.web.com/article/1414
label: Article
entityId: I am using the personal tab entityId from the manifest.
I am seeking advice on whether this is the correct way to create a deep link for my Teams tab. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to deep link to a sub page in your app directly like this, but it's possible to do what you're trying to do overall in general, just in a different way. `webUrl` won't work because that's only a fallback for scenarios when Teams can't open the deep link directly, like on certain devices - it's not even getting used in your scenario.

Instead, look to use a one or more of the context or other parameters options built for this. For instance, you can use `context.subEntityId` to hold "article" and "1414" or `entityLabel` or `subEntityLabel` to hold "article" and `context.subEntityId` to hold "1414", and then you'd need to handle the rendering of that in your angular app appropriately (e.g. have a page specifically to deal with this incoming scenario, or do a redirect internally, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the following to make it work:

```
let encodedContext = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({"subEntityId": "article/4141"}));
var taskItemUrl = 'https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/fe4a8eba-2a31-4737-8e33-e5fae6fee194/tasklist123?context=' + encodedContext;
```

Then adding a redirect guard to check for `context.page.id` within context data.